# TitleState.hx:531: characters 6-28 : Bool cannot be called

Tags: haxeflixel

im having a problem executing a OnClickFuntion in Haxeflixel

```
if(FlxG.mouse.justPressed(logo2))
    {
        MusicBeatState.switchState(new StoryMenuState());
    }
```

i would love help in need of confusion!..
and yes the Mouse variable is set to true!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
`FlxG.mouse.justPressed`  just checks if you... well.. just pressed to mouse.

To do what you are trying to achieve, you can check if the mouse overlaps the sprite.
Something like this:

```
if(FlxG.mouse.justPressed && FlxG.mouse.overlaps(logo2))
{
        MusicBeatState.switchState(new StoryMenuState());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[justPressed](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/input/mouse/FlxMouse.html#justPressed) is Bool variable, so should be like below

```
if(FlxG.mouse.justPressed)
```

Comment: yeah but i want to be where if you click the variable (flxsprite) it switches the state